# How to solve $\int_{1}^{e^2}\ \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2}x+\ln x}$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

How to calculate this integral 
$$\int_{1}^{e^2}\ \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2}x+\ln x}\ \ ?$$

Comment: I don't think that it's algebraically feasible : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate_1%5E(e%5E2)1%2F(sqrt(2)x%2Bln(x))

Comment: have you tried the change of variable $ z= \log(x)$ ?

Comment: @Surb I think people should start using their fantasy, instead of Mathematica. Look at the awesome answer below, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Max said in a comment, we can change the variable:

$$\ln x=z$$

$$x=e^z$$

$$\int^{e^2}_1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2}x+\ln x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int^{2}_0 \frac{dz}{1+\dfrac{z}{\sqrt{2}e^z}}=$$

$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int^{2}_0 \left(1-\frac{z e^{-z}}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{z^2 e^{-2z}}{2}-\frac{z^3 e^{-3z}}{\sqrt{2^3}}+\dots \right)dz$$

For $x \in [0,2]$ it follows that $\dfrac{z}{\sqrt{2}e^z}<1$, so the series converges.

$$\int^{e^2}_1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2}x+\ln x}=\sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sum^{\infty}_{k=1} \frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{2^k}} \int^{2}_0 z^k e^{-kz} dz$$

The integrals have the following general form:

$$\int^{2}_0 z^k e^{-kz} dz=\frac{k!}{k^{k+1}} \left(1-e^{-2k} \sum^{k}_{l=0} \frac{(2k)^l}{l!} \right)$$

For example:

$$\int^{2}_0 z e^{-z} dz=1-\frac{3}{e^2}=0.59399$$

$$\int^{2}_0 z^2 e^{-2z} dz=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{13}{4e^4}=0.19047$$

Now the final solution would be:

$$\int^{e^2}_1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2}x+\ln x}=\sqrt{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sum^{\infty}_{k=1} \frac{(-1)^k k!}{\sqrt{2^k} k^{k+1}} \left(1-e^{-2k} \sum^{k}_{l=0} \frac{(2k)^l}{l!} \right)$$

Keeping only terms up to $k=2$ (which is a positive term) leads us to the approximate value:

$$\int^{e^2}_1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2}x+\ln x}<1.18456$$

Adding a term for $k=3$ (which is a negative term) leads us to the approximate value:

$$\int^{e^2}_1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2}x+\ln x}>1.16884$$

Considering the numerical solution, we got a good approximation, which can be made as close to the exact solution as we want with additional terms.

$$\int^{e^2}_1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2}x+\ln x}=1.17185$$

Comment: Awesome answer! I was going to answer too, with a different try but I really liked yours! Well done. People should be like you, using their fantasy and their skills! +1

Answer (score 3):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment.*

Starting from Yuriy S's nice answer, we can partly simplify at least the notations using the fact that $$I_k=\int^{2}_0 z^k e^{-kz} dz=\frac{\Gamma (k+1)-\Gamma (k+1,2 k)}{k^{k+1} }$$ and observe that $$\log\Big(\frac{I_k}{\sqrt{2^k}}\Big) \approx - 1.37009\, k$$ which, for a required accuracy, gives the number of terms to be used.

So, using $10$ terms should in principle, lead to a error $\approx 10^{-6}$. Using Yuriy S's formula for $10$ terms, the integral is $1.17185022$ while numerical integration would lead to $\approx 1.17185006$